# Finding "cold spots" with `perf`

Tags: multithreading, performance, perf

Running a `perf record`/`perf annotate` cycle generates information about what assembly instructions are "hot", in that they are being executed over and over.

However, for certain performance problems, we want to know where a function is "cold". This often happens in multithreaded environments, where some sort of resource contention, such as mutexes being held for too long, cause underutilization of the architecture.

How can I understand "cold spots" from a `perf.data` file?

Comment: When you say "cold" spots, do you mean code that's executing while other threads are blocked by a mutex like you describe?  Or do you mean the normal definition of "cold": code that simply doesn't run very often if ever.  (e.g. error handling normally doesn't run at all.)

Comment: You can pin your thread and trace the activity of other threads with perf to analyze any problem happening while your target function is executed (not very precise though and require the hot function to be executed on well defined threads in a deterministic way).

Comment: @PeterCordes: My mistake for misusing language: I mean code that (for example) runs very few instructions per cycle, or does nothing as it waits for a mutex release.

Comment: Hello, check the Off-CPU profiling (or combined on-cpu + off-cpu) http://www.brendangregg.com/offcpuanalysis.html http://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/offcpuflamegraphs.html http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2015-02-26/linux-perf-off-cpu-flame-graph.html